# Does switching the bard incantation stat from charisma to wisdom create major balance issues?

Tags: dnd-5e, ability-scores, spellcasting, bard

I have a player who want to play a shaman. He really wants to keep the bard classes but he is much more interested in the druid lore. He doesn't want to be charismatic and handle social interaction, he wants to focus it's music around nature and worship nature-related deities. Therefore he was asking if he can have a bard with wisdom as the incantation  characteristic.

I'm about to say yes, but I'm new and I don't know if there is major balance issues that will come up and that I didn't foresee.

Comment: Related questions: "[What are the ramifications of switching the spellcasting ability of a class?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/69024)" and "[What are the impacts of changing a Ranger's spellcasting ability?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/128756)" and "[What are the possible balance implications for houseruling INT as Paladin's spellcasting ability and class features?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/156103)"

Comment: While I wouldn't necessarily close a more specific Q as the dupe of a wider one, in this case the other also mainly deals with a cha>wis change. If there is a specific problem you would anticipate with a bard that is not addressed there, feel free to edit the question to focus on that.